# How to have a shared environment variable for Angular 2 and ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have an Angular 2 application in an ASP.NET Core MVC project. Both Angular 2 application and `Startup.cs` will have code for specific environments, ie. use `http://localhost` as web service url instead of `http://devserver`(should be used when published). I need to do this programmatically so I rather do not do this without setting `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the OS. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? Do you just want to separate concerns of different environments or do you want to be able to change these values while the application is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this. Not sure if it's an optimal solution but it works for me.

**Please do note, in the end I've chosen a configuration-based file (ie. use .Debug.file if your in Debug configuration) for config as a solution, not environment-variable-based.**

Create `appsettings.json`. This will be read when you press F5 to run the project in debug mode. Also set `appsettings.json` "`Copy to Output directory: Copy if newer`":

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "MyApiUrl": "http://localhost:23224/v1/"
  }
}
```

Create `appsettings.Debug.json`. This will be used when you publish the project (assuming you are using `Debug` configuration for publish):

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "MyApiUrl": "http://api.server.com/v1/"
  }
}
```

Edit your `.csproj` to add `AfterBuild` event to copy `appsettings.json` file to `/wwwroot` when you build (assuming your Angular 2 application is in wwwroot folder) so Angular can read it:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuildOperations" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)appsettings.json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)wwwroot\appsettings.json" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```

Edit your `.csproj` to rename `appsettings.Debug.json` to `appsettings.json` and copy it to `wwwroot` folder when you publish it. For some reason VS.NET publish includes both appsettings.json and appsettings.Debug.json in the publish output folder:

```
<Target Name="AfterPublishOperations" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\PublishOutput\appsettings.json" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\PublishOutput\appsettings.$(ConfigurationName).json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\PublishOutput\appsettings.json" />
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\PublishOutput\appsettings.$(ConfigurationName).json" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\PublishOutput\appsettings.json" DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\PublishOutput\wwwroot\appsettings.json" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
  </Target>
```

Add `AppSettings.cs` model to your project to get configuration strongly-typed:

```
public class AppSettings
    {
        public string MyApiUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Read `appsettings.json` contents in `Startup.cs` and add it as a singleton to DI container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var appSettings = ReadConfiguration();
            services.AddSingleton(appSettings);
        }

        public AppSettings ReadConfiguration()
        {
            var section = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            var settings = new AppSettings();
            new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<AppSettings>(section).Configure(settings);

            return settings;
        }
```

You can inject AppSettings to your controllers:

```
private AppSettings appSettings;

public MyController(AppSettings appSettings)
{
    this.appSettings = appSettings;
}
```

Add `AppSettings.ts` to your Angular 2

```
export interface AppSettings {
    MyApiUrl?: string;
}
```

Now you can read it anywhere you want in Angular 2:

```
private ReadAppSettings() {
        this.http.get('/appsettings.json')
            .map(response => response.json())
            .subscribe(result => {
                let appSettings: AppSettings = <AppSettings>result.AppSettings;
            },
            error => { console.error(error); });
    }
```